# Php calling javascript on load

Tags: php, javascript

Guys i have little problem with PHP to call Javascript function on load ...
Idea is when page load i do little calculation with PHP stuff , so when i finish that all i 
want is to write that down in same DOM element using javascript.
I will not show you PHP code for calculation as i am 100% sure it is alright.
This is the code i got so far , so can you just tell me whats wrong with it?

```
$test = 100;
echo "<script language=javascript> window.onload=UpdatePoints($test); </script>";
```

and Javascript function is simple

```
function UpdatePoints(Points) {
document.getElementById('PointsNumber').innerHTML = Points;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "when page load i do little calculation with PHP stuff" --- actually all the calculations are **already done** when page is loading

Comment: that is correct ... was just grammar mistake

Comment: @zerkms that is usually true but it is possible to flush the data before the script is finished executing - though in this case that is not happening.

Comment: What is _not working_? Is there an error message?

Comment: `$test` contains numeric value or string value if string then enclosed in single quote.

Comment: invalid HTML used. script tag should be written as `<script type="text/javascript">`. Also, you should just add the `UpdatePoints(Points)` function to your `<body>` onload.

Comment: @DC_: right, but for newbie it's better to think that these 2 processes are not simultaneous.

Comment: @zerkms Agreed, just pointing that out for future viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling the function `UpdatePoints()` in `window.onload`, you need to wrap the call in a function that gets assigned by reference to `window.onload`.  Otherwise, you are calling the function, and assigning its return value to `window.onload`.

```
// This function wraps UpdatePoints($test)
// and is assigned as a reference to window.onload
function load() {
  UpdatePoints(<?php echo $test; ?>);
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.onload=load; </script>";
```

Note that the `language` attribute to the `<script>` tag is deprecated. Include a `type=text/javascript` attribute in its place (though text/javascript is genearlly the browser default)

However, since the value of `$test` is created before the page loads and cannot change when the function is called, you might as well not bother passing it as a parameter, in which case you don't need to wrap the function. Just remove the `()` to assign it as a reference.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.onload=UpdatePoints; </script>";

function UpdatePoints() {
  // PHP write directly into the function since the value
  // can't change...  It's always going to be passed as what PHP assigns 
  // if you call it as UpdatePoints($test)
  var Points = $test;
  document.getElementById('PointsNumber').innerHTML = Points;
}
```